# Help! Trying to install gnome tweaks for the first time

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-tweaks

I'm trying to install gnome tweaks on pop_os with the command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

after running the command I stumbled with this prompt:

`Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 1102 (packagekitd)`

Is there something I should be doing before this? online videos are not really specific about this.

Comment: It means another process is using dpkg.  You need to wait until that finishes. You need to run `sudo apt update` before you run anything else in `apt` and if you're going to add or remove software, you should also make sure everything is up-to-date with `sudo apt upgrade`. Otherwise you're increasing the chance that you're going to break something. FYI: Pop!OS is off topic here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sounds like you have another process or maybe another window also trying to do an install.  Do you have the software center or something open?  Are you doing another install in a different terminal window?  If all else fails, maybe reboot?

Comment: I think I DID click an install update notification, which opened the pop_shop into the installed tab. could that be the cause?

Comment: I am not familiar with Pop, so cannot really say.  Process 1102 is what has the file locked.  You can run `ps 1102` to see what is running in that process.